# Trying to connect to servlet from Android Emulator, doesn't work?

Tags: android, servlets, android-emulator, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to connect to a servlet in localhost from my Android Emulator.

I created a project in Eclipse named SimpleHttpGetRequest with an activity named "HttpGetServletActivity".

I created in NetBeans a project named "HttpGetRequest" containing a servlet.

The code in my "HttpGetServletActivity" activity is :

```
package com.mobdev.simplehttprequest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HttpGetServletActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button button;
TextView outputText;

public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/HttpGetRequest/HelloWorldServlet";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewsById();

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void findViewsById() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{ URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                output.append(s);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("get");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        outputText.setText(output);
    }
}
}
```

The source code of my servlet is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

public HelloWorldServlet() {
    super();
}

    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello Android !!!!");
}
}
```

- I deployed my servlet in Apache server (i'm using xampp);
- I added permission for network connection

When I run my App and click on the button, the App crashes, and I don't know why !!
Can anybody help me, please ? Im' stuck.

I tried :

- Wifi connection : I did run my App on a real device, instead of "10.0.2.2" I put the ip adress of     my PC but it doesn't work ;
- Access to project HttpGetrequest from Android Emulator browser, it worked ;

Comment: Do you have any output from logcat to share about the crash?

Comment: findViewsById(); it's a method that I defined.

private void findViewsById() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);
}

Comment: @Omar : OK, apologies, I hadn't spotted that. It is a confusing method name as it is so close to the native `findViewById(...)` method.

Comment: @Omar : If it works from the browser with IP 10.0.2.2 then that's being routed to your PC's localhost address. Over wifi it could be a firewall rule blocking the connection - try turning your firewall off temporarily.

Comment: I already did that, I disabled my firewall and It didn't work.
I saved a log file, how can I post it in a comment?

Comment: @Omar : In that case I've no further ideas. I'd only say, as commented by Robrt Karl, edit your question and add the logcat errors from logcat when trying it on your phone.

Comment: @RobertKarl how can I post my log file ? it's too long !

Comment: `button.setOnClickListener(this);` What should do `this` in this case?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh my Activity implements OnClickListener so..

Comment: @Omar: Oh yeah, When you type `URL` in your browser, it works?